# Secured spring request handler with Apikey and user roles using spring lemon

Tags: spring-lemon

Can I be enriched with some code snippets for securing certain request handlers with user roles and apikey using spring lemon please.

Answer (score 0):

How to use API key to authenticate is actually a different question from how to have role based authorizations, because whether you use API key or username/password for authentication, the authorization pattern is going to be the same. For authorization, Spring Lemon uses service method level authorization. Look at the use of @PreAuthorize and @UserEditPermission in [LemonService](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/naturalprogrammer/spring/lemon/LemonService.java) as examples.

For creating and using API key, have a look at the [API documentation](https://naturalprogrammer.github.io/apidocs/lemon-demo-0.12.0-api.html#_create_api_key) and let me know if you have any specific questions. BTW, the [getting started video tutorial](https://gum.co/IKqz) showcases creating the API key.